# Closed form of $\int_{0}^{1} \frac{x\log x\log(\frac{1+x}{1-x})}{1-x^2} dx$

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

> I need a closed form using Mathematica or otherwise of the integral $$\int_{0}^{1} \frac{x\log x\log(\frac{1+x}{1-x})}{1-x^2} dx $$

This integral converges [see here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=integral+x+log+x+log%28%281%2Bx%29%2F%281-x%29%29%2F%281-x%5E2%29+from+0+to+1).

I am requesting a code with answer if possible in Wolfram Mathematica.

I am a beginner in Wolfram Mathematica.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `Integrate[(x Log[x] Log[(1 + x)/(1 - x)])/(1 - x^2), {x, 0, 1}]` gives `1/8 (-π^2 Log[4] + 7 Zeta[3])`.

Comment: @Syed Thanks a lot

Comment: If you have started learning Mathematica, then you will find that the introductory [book](https://www.wolfram.com/language/elementary-introduction/2nd-ed/) written by the inventor is a good learning resource. There is a [fast intro for math students](https://www.wolfram.com/language/fast-introduction-for-math-students/en/) as well as a [fast intro for programmers](https://www.wolfram.com/language/fast-introduction-for-programmers/en/) to choose from.

Comment: Max, it is not the first post of this kind from you here. You have to do the typing. It looks like you are asking people to type your homeworks.

Comment: @Syed I kindly ask you not to answer such posts. A good post should show at least a minimum of work. You do a bad service to these people and to the community.

Comment: You have a point @yarchik.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vs 13.2 gives

```
 Integrate[(x Log[x] Log[(1 + x)/(1 - x)])/(1 - x^2), {x, 0, 1}]



 1/8 (-\[Pi]^2 Log[4] + 7 Zeta[3])
```

You may enter the traditional form using e.g. the Menu/Palettes/BasicMathAssistant or with some typing experience you type 2d symbols by escape sequences

> Esc dintt Esc

You will find out about all the shortcuts if you hover with the mouse over the BasicMathAssistant